# Cibuildwheel Fails to Compile With Static Libraries

Tags: python, c, linker, continuous-integration, python-c-api

I have a Python C extension module which relies on static libraries. Below is my file tree, I haven't included all the files because I am trying to simplify the problem.

```
folder/
├── src/
|   ├── main.c
|   └── other.c
├── include/
|   ├── glfw3native.h
|   └── glfw3.h
├── lib/
|   └── libglfw3.a
└── setup.py
```

Below is my `setup.py` file, I have removed some unnecessary lines.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    ext_modules = [
        setuptools.Extension(
            "Module.__init__", ["src/main.c", "src/other.c"],
            include_dirs = ["include"],
            library_dirs = ["lib"],
            libraries = ["glfw"])
    ])
```

I can successfully compile my project with the following command.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Now I want to use `cibuildtools` to compile my project for multiple platforms.

```
cibuildwheel --platform linux
```

For some reason, the program crashes when it tries to link the libraries. Even though the library path is stated, it shows the following error.

```
cannot find -lglfw
```

Why does this happen when compiling with `cibuildwheel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because static binaries are different on every system, I need to compile my libraries on the corresponding platform. In the end, I used the `CIBW_BEFORE_ALL` variable to execute the build commands for my libraries.